# How is differential signalling AC?

Tags: differential

My initial understanding was that each differential signal (such as those used for encoders, e.g. A and inverse of A) travels along its own line and is unconnected to its inverse, etc.

However, I've been informed that differential signalling is actually AC, where the signal's inverse line effectively completes the circuit.

Could somebody explain exactly how differential signalling is handled, what happens in the wire, etc?

Comment: what research have you done? ... this kind if information is already on the web ..... i think that you need to start with the definition of AC signal

Comment: @jsotola, could you kindly provide me with some good links?

Comment: you have not answered my question .......... http://www.dummies.com/education/science/science-electronics/electronics-basics-direct-and-alternating-current/

Comment: @jsotola, thank you. What is confusing me is how the current can alternate when the inverse line's voltage is always < the opposite line.

Comment: @jsotola, I had already briefly read up on AC which I feel I have a basic understanding of. I'm just struggling to see how the signal is actually DC, for reasons mentioned above, and in response to the answer below.

Comment: you are misunderstanding what AC is ..... any change in the value makes it AC (basically anything other than DC) .... it does not have to reverse direction

Comment: "any change in value" - are you referring to any change in voltage? So, I am right in thinking the current always flows in one direction, in this case? Most of the resources I've read, including the one you linked to seem to suggest that the potential difference between two points in a circuit oscillates between a positive and negative voltage, hence the change in current direction.

Comment: part of the problem is that you do not have a clear understanding of the basics .... please google `ohm's law` to learn how voltage, current and resistance interact

Comment: @jsotola, which part of my description didn't make sense?

Comment: AC stands for "alternating current" ... you asked `are you referring to any change in voltage?` ..... if you understood ohm's law then you would know that it is both current and voltage

Comment: Yes, I now realise that didn't make much sense. I do realise though that a change in voltage means a change in current (assuming the resistance is constant). A quick Google search showed that AC signals can take the form of a square wave. Can the signal be AC if the voltage is above zero? Wouldn't that just be a pulsed current?

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/alternating-current-ac-vs-direct-current-dc - "Alternating current describes the flow of charge that changes direction periodically." Suggests a change in direction is needed for it to be AC.

Comment: **Actually, all signaling is AC** because the information is carried in the change.  You can decompose any voltage or current into the sum of a steady part and a changing part.  All of the information is carried in the changing part, which is AC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A electrical **signal** is used to transfer *information* from one point to another. (This is generally different to transmitting *power* from one point to another although in many cases it can be both. Take a simple doorbell, for example: is that a signalling system or a power system? One could argue that it is either or both.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0i7iz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A differential output. A1 and A2 are 180° out of phase.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The differential outputs are 0 - 5 V logic levels. A1 and A2 are out of phase. When A1 is high (1), A2 is low (2).*

Now a question for you: are those signals AC or not?

There are several ways of answering:

1. **No**. The polarity of each signal is always either zero or positive. Neither signal ever goes negative with respect to GND. The current is there or not there but never "alternates" in the sense of changing dirction.
2. **Yes**. That signal can be thought of as 2.5 V DC (the mid-voltage) with a ±2.5 V squarewave superimposed on it. The squarewave in this case is definitely AC. The result then is a DC signal with AC superimposed on it.
3. **Yes**. The signals alternate relative to each other. If you connect meter negative probe to A2 then A1 will alternate between + and - relative to A2.

There is a third way that makes it a bit more definite.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm7dVS.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. A termination resistor has been added. We can monitor current through the resistor.*

[image]

*Figure 4. The resultant waveforms for Figure 3. Notice that while A1 and A2 never go negative that the current direction in R1 does.*

4. **Yes**. Now we can see that the *current* in Figure 4 is indeed AC.

---

> My initial understanding was that each differential signal (such as those used for encoders, e.g. A and inverse of A) travels along it's own line and is unconnected to its inverse, etc.

Even without R1 in my circuit the signals will be fed into amplifiers with the same ground reference so they will always be at least indirectly referenced to each other.

I don't think that trying to think of the signals as AC is very helpful. The signal might never change - the status of a switch, for example, or your encoder on a stationary shaft - and strictly speaking that is now a DC signal.

> However, I've been informed that differential signalling is actually AC, where the signal's inverse line effectively completes the circuit.

I think my points above show how that line of thinking can be supported (but I don't think it's a helpful way of thinking about it).

> So, why don't we use a single wire for all signalling?

Immunity to noise. If noise is injected on a single line signal it may push it over or under the receiver switching threshold giving false values or counts. With differential signalling both lines would see the same interference but any common-mode interference cancels out when we get the *difference* between the signals by subtraction.

e.g., if we have a signal \$ A \$ and \$ -A \$ with common-mode noise \$ n \$ on each then when we subtract the signals from each other we get \$ A + n - (-A + n) = A + n + A - n = 2 A \$. Double the signal and none of the noise!

> Could somebody explain exactly how differential signalling is handled, what happens in the wire, etc?

You can consider each of the differential wires as individual signal transmission. The smart stuff happens at the receiver where a differential amplifier is used.

---

From the comments:

> 1. By connecting the two transmission lines (even though a resistor is between the two), wouldn't that mean that both input pins would register a high, when the opposite line is high? Or is the resistor enough to lower the voltage?

No each output uses a transistor to pull high or low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN1c1v.png)</sup>

*Figure 5. The differential output stage and its equivalents.*

You seem to be forgetting that each of the output stages are push-pull. A transistor connects the output to either V+ or GND and provides a strong pull in that direction. I've attempted to show that here where the buffer is pulling high (M1 on) and the inverter is pulling low (M4 on).

2. I've found an example where one of the lines goes below 0 (murata.com/en-eu/products/emiconfun/emc/2013/10/15/…). The diagram suggests, as I suspected, that current always flows in one direction.

It's not clear which figure you are referring to. All the outputs in those (rather small) diagrams seem to be 0 to 5 V switching as in all my examples.

And then ...

> ... so basically works like a pull/up down resistor.

Not quite. Probably the opposite. A pull-up/down resistor works as a poor-man's version of these switches. A switch is much more definite than a pull-up because it can usually source or sink a lot more current. When the switch and a pull-up/down resistor fight it out the resistor value is chosen so that the switch will always win.

> Zoom in on figure 3. I can see some negative signs in there.

[image]

*Figure 6. Fig 3 of the linked article.*

The drawing is not correct, I think. A differential signal needs to have the polarities cross over at the switching point. The input signals on that diagram spend half their time with both at zero volts. This is the worst possible condition as the comparitor will randomly switch high and low with any slight deviation between the inputs caused by noise. It would be fine if both inputs were switching between the same voltages - whatever those voltages happen to be.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense to me. I think the confusion was coming from my assumption that the inverse line was always negative (and always of a lower voltage than the opposite line), therefore current would always flow in the same direction through the resistor. Can you confirm this in your answer, and I'll accept it?

Comment: I think I've already covered it. See Figure 1. Both signals switch between 0 and +5 in my example and are never negative. Note that in another scheme they could be but that's not the point. The point of differential signalling is that the polarity changes *between the signals* relative to each other and not to ground. Because of this the current changes direction through the resistor. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: So you wouldn't expect to find a differential signal where one line switches between 0 and 5, and the other between 0 and -5, for example? Regardless, in this case current would always flow in one direction? "The point of differential signalling is that the polarity changes between the signals relative to each other and not to ground" - by polarity do you mean current direction?

Comment: (1) "*... one line switches between 0 and 5, and the other between 0 and -5,*" No. I have never seen such a scheme. (2) "*... by polarity do you mean current direction?*" Since the load is a resistor the voltage will be proportional to the current. Both voltage across the resistor and current through  the resistor will change simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, thank you. You've cleared that up beautifully. :)

Comment: Just a few thoughts that have come to mind:
1) By connecting the two transmission lines (even though a resistor is between the two), wouldn't that mean that both input pins would register a high, when the opposite line is high? Or is the resistor enough to lower the voltage?

2) I've found an example where one of the lines goes below 0 (https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/emiconfun/emc/2013/10/15/en-20131015-p1). The diagram suggests, as I suspected, that current always flows in one direction.

Comment: See Figure 5, etc.

Comment: Ahhhhh, ok, so basically works like a pull/up down resistor.
Zoom in on figure 3. I can see some negative signs in there.

Comment: See Figure 6, etc. Gone to mow the lawn. It's 21:30 in the west of Ireland and still bright daylight.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a risk of the two signals being received out of sync (skewing), as is often the case with long parallel lines?

Comment: That's a separate question I think. Can we close this one out now? Thank you for accepting my answer. Lawn is cut.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the voltage between the two signal lines, you will find that for one logic state ("1"), the "+" line will be at a higher (more positive) voltage than the "-" line.  For the other logic state ("0"), the "-" line will be at a higher voltage than the "+" line, so there is an alternating voltage between the two signal lines, although both lines may be at a positive voltage at all times.

If you have a terminating resistor between the signal lines, the current in that resistor will change directions with the logic state.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the two lines in a terminated differential pair.

- One line has a +ve voltage on it, and is passing a current to the receiver.
- The other line has a negative voltage on it, and is drawing a current from the receiver.

At the receiver, let's put the termination resistor directly between the two lines. Current flows through the termination resistor from one line to the other. There is a differential voltage across the resistor, between one line and the other.

If instead we use two separate termination resistors, one from each line to ground, to keep each line 'unconnected' to its inverse, then we have the following. Current flows through each termination resistor, from one line, to the other line, with no net signal current flowing to ground as equal currents flow in and out of the ground connections. There is a differential voltage between one line and the other, half of which appears across each resistor.

Apart from the connection to ground which carries no signal current, there's no difference between the two scenarios. The ground connection might carry a DC current, if the signal sources have a DC bias with respect to ground, but the differential signal currents are equal and opposite and always cancel in the ground.

Signalling is, by definition, AC, as we need changes to transmit information. A steady DC level transmits no information. However, if the data rate is low enough, if the changes in level are few and far between, some people do casually talk about DC signalling, and usually their audience understands what they mean, and is polite enough not to insist on being pedantic.

There *is* a distinction between signalling systems that are DC coupled, where a DC level that's sustained for a long time is recognised as a valid state, and AC coupled systems where changes are always needed at a certain minimum rate to make coupling transformers work or to maintain synchronisation. However, that distinction has nothing to do with whether the signalling is single-ended or differential.

Answer (score 0):

By definition an AC signal, or power, is one where one line goes above zero volts while the other line goes below zero volts. The sum of the signal/power for 1 second is zero volts, assuming an equal number of positive and negative cycles. However that is just summing FP numbers. According to \$V^2\$ and \$I^2\$ power was applied and consumed, because negative values are treated as absolute values.

Differential signaling has a pair of wires where both wires have a common mode 'n' volts above ground, and send ones and zeros by switching positions relative to some common center line. USB is like this. The supply is 5 volts with a ground return. To send data the signal wires take turns swinging above or below the center 2.5 volt point.

Ethernet *can* be truly differential as it is current based, from transformer to transformer normally. However there is PoE (Power over Ethernet) in which a voltage of about 48 VDC is applied to the outer pairs through center taped transformers, and recovered by the end user and converted to a few watts of power.

There is a chance that the power source has an Earth ground, but since Ethernet 'floats' it is not an issue. Some routers may implement a high-impedance ground with 1 meg resistors to prevent floating outside of the 500 volt isolation the transformers offer.

PCIe is ultra-fast differential communications confined to motherboards. The common load might be a 22 ohm resistor to 1.35 volts, so once again we have a differential signal in the GHZ range that sends ones and zeros by shifting opposing pairs only 250 mV or so, and is capacitively coupled at each end.

RS-232 and RS-485 do swing above and below ground, with RS-485 being a more strict standard and a much faster data rate, and is protocol independent. *Since RS-485 has substantially low load resistors there is a change in current flow, but not at the high-impedance receivers, which see only the voltages change state.*

There are many communication protocols and many physical layers to transport them, so read lots of books and search the web for Users Guides, etc.

Comment: Figure 2 (https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/emiconfun/emc/2013/10/15/en-20131015-p1) seems to suggest that current is always flowing in one direction (which kind of makes sense when you consider that the inverse line voltage is always lower in voltage than the other). Doesn't alternating current suggest that the current moves in both directions?

Comment: You are confusing current with voltage. Signaling only requires a symmetrical voltage change to pass data. You are partially correct in that Ethernet actually does change current flow to send data. AC power is obvious that the current reverses 50/60 times a second. But a change in voltage levels for say USB, is just that. There is a tiny change in current flow due to end-point resistors, but it is the voltage shift the receiver is looking for. In some cases current shift dominates while in others the voltage shift dominates.

Comment: Hi, @Sparky: "*... an AC signal, or power, is one where one line goes above zero volts while the other line goes below zero volts.*" My domestic AC supply fails this definition as the neutral wire stays at (within reason) zero volts. "*The sum of the signal/power for 1 second is zero volts, assuming an equal number of positive and negative cycles.*". While the average of the signal may be zero the power (for a resistive load) won't be as the \$ V^2 \$ or \$ I^2 \$ will make the power always positive. I know you know all this. It's just come out garbled. Edit required?

Comment: Hmmmm, still quite confused. When you say a tiny change in current flow, do you mean a change in direction? How is a change in current direction possible when the inverse always has a lower voltage? Doesn't the current always flow in the direction towards the lower voltage?

Comment: In the inverse symbol state, the a_inverse signal is driven With a higher voltage than the 'a' signal.

Comment: @B4039. With voltage level receivers like RS-485 the current change is in the nano-amps. If you want to get down to femto-amps, sure, the meter will show a change. That is why I tried to show there is a difference between a current driven signal vs. a voltage driven signal, such that only one dominates during an exchange of data.